# composer package bin directory and php exec with SELinux

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7, selinux

Im running a composer package that provides an executable in the `/bin` directory.
Now I want to execute this binary using php's `exec()` function.

This seems to be blocked by centos' SELinux ("Permission denied").

What `context` do I have to apply on which directory/file to make this work?